# Sending email using CDOSYS without authentication?

Tags: asp.net, email, asp-classic, cdo.message

I had to redo a script using the following start and end code in ASP using CDOSYS.  (I do not know much about ASP or ASP.NET)  The smtp I used requires user/pass auth. yet the E-Mail sent anyways without me putting that info.  Does this mean the smtp server allows relaying with only the E-Mail address?

```
<%
Set Mailer = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
 If IsObject(Mailer) = True Then


'header'
Mailer.From = request.Form("FROM")
Mailer.To="email@host.ca"
Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2

Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.host.ca"

Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25

Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Update

Mailer.send
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupid me.

I did not Tshoot enough.  My MTA allows domain to domain (my Email to my Email) relay.  However if I tried my E-Mail to another Email (domain) I get  Relay access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this technology is being used exatcly for the simplifying the messaging:

[ASP Sending e-mail with CDOSYS](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp):

> > CDO (Collaboration Data Objects) is a Microsoft technology that is designed to simplify the creation of messaging applications.
> >
> > CDOSYS is a built-in component in ASP. We will show you how to use this component to send e-mail with ASP.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean the smtp server allows relaying with only the E-Mail address?

It "depends" on server/mta setup:

- IP whitelist
- If it has other "Post offices" (domains), perhaps it allows relaying between them (aka "internal").

It's been some time since I've worked with SMTP/MTAs directly, so I'm sure those with more/current experience can provide more examples of "relay restriction rules"..

Comment: thanks for the comments.  I don't like to assume, but if I assumed I would get it if its relaying if the script would be in my network but it was outside my network, still accessed my mta (POSTFIX) and sent mail without user/pass.  I tried a php script and it worked as well without user/pass.